# Dell Boomi: How to add multiple attachments to one email

Tags: integration

I hope anyone can help me with this simple problem I have with Dell Boomi.

I have an integration flow where I get several documents from an instance. I want those documents mailed to my emailadress. But now I get 8 mails, with 8 documents. What I want is one mail, with 8 documents attached. It seems so easy but I can not find this in Boomi, or elsewhere online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data process shape to combine the documents and then send to the Mail connector.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you added links to documentation about Data process shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IMAP MAIL Connector to send mail with one or more attachments.
You need to add your document to cache and then use it in the imap mail connector operation.
The number of your documents will be the number of attachments. 
Can refer to - 
https://community.boomi.com/s/article/howtousethemailimapconnector

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the Salesforce community page:

How to send multiple attachments through mail connector?
Solution
Solution
Currently sending multiple attachments via mail is not possible.But you can send multiple attachments as a single attachment via email by zipping all the attachments to a single zip file.

If you would like to have this feature in Boomi,please raise a feedback request on Boomi’s Feedback Forum, which is accessible through the Help & Feedback dropdown menu in Boomi AtomSphere.

How to Zip files? Please go through the article "Combining files into a zip"

Answer (score 0):

Use Data process to Zip all the files and pass them through email connector as single attachment.